# Map (deserialize) JSON API result that contains the object's properties as a numbered list

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I've searched SO and google for a similar question, but couldn't find the exact thing I'm searching for.

I'm developing an application that queries an API that returns the following result:

```
{
    "Ticket": {
        "1": {
            "DisplayName": "Ticket ID",
            "Value": 117
        },
        "2": {
            "DisplayName": "Last Modified",
            "Value": "2022-10-05T18:09:32.1070000Z"
        },
        "3": {
            "DisplayName": "Last User",
            "Value": "SYSTEMACCOUNT"
        },
        "4": {
            "DisplayName": "Seq_Group",
            "Value": 1
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want to deserialize it to an object like the following:

```cs
public class Ticket 
{
    public property int TicketID {get; set;}
    public property DateTime LastModified {get; set;}
    public property string LastUser {get; set;}
    public property int Seq_Group {get; set;}
}
```

(there are several more properties hidden here for brevity)

Can you point me in the direction of how to do the mapping in the best way?

I know I could deserialize it to a Dictionary and then iterate the dictionary with several ifs and elses, but I think there must be a smarter way to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: @LLL There isn't a more direct way to do that, then? Like with a JsonConverter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need only one line of code

```
Ticket ticket =  new JObject( ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["Ticket"]).Properties()
      .Select(t=> new JProperty((string) t.Value["DisplayName"], t.Value["Value"])))
      .ToObject<Ticket>();
```

and fix your class

```
public class Ticket
{
    [JsonProperty("Ticket ID")]
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("Last Modified")]
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("Last User")]
    public string LastUser { get; set; }
    
    public int Seq_Group { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [`JsonConstructorAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) and *System.Reflection* for the property mapping.

1. Use of the `[DisplayName]` attribute to define which property name should be mapped from the JSON.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel; 

public class Ticket 
{
    [DisplayName("Ticket ID")]
    public int TicketID {get; set;}
    [DisplayName("Last Modified")]
    public DateTime LastModified {get; set;}
    [DisplayName("Last User")]
    public string LastUser {get; set;}
    public int Seq_Group {get; set;}    
}
```

2. An extension method to retrieve the property name from the `[DisplayName]` attribute (if applied) or its default property name.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Reflection;

public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static string ToName(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            object[] displayNameAttributes = propertyInfo
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false)
                .ToArray();

            if (displayNameAttributes != null && displayNameAttributes.Count() > 0)
                return ((DisplayNameAttribute)displayNameAttributes[0]).DisplayName;

            return propertyInfo.Name;
        }
        catch
        {
            return propertyInfo.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Implement the conversion logic in the constructor by applying the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

public class Root
{
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Root(Dictionary<string, JObject> ticket)
    {
        Ticket = new Ticket();
        
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JObject> kvp in ticket)
        {
            string propertyName = kvp.Value.SelectToken("DisplayName").ToString();
            
            PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(Ticket).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToName() == propertyName);
            if (propInfo != null)
            {
                JToken value = kvp.Value.SelectToken("Value");
                
                Type propType = propInfo.PropertyType;
                if (propType == typeof(DateTime))
                    propInfo.SetValue(Ticket, DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()));                
                else
                    propInfo.SetValue(Ticket, value.ToObject(propType));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yHJhkn)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't heard about JsonConstructor before. I'll try that. :)